# How can we implement overlay effect in cocos2d for my game

Tags: cocos2d-x

We have a guy whose shooting range is denoted by a transparent circle. We want to have overlay affect in that transparent layer, as it works in Photoshop.

Basically that will highlight all the elements which comes in that range.

How can we do the same effect in cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll look exactly like you expect, but I'd do something like this:

For circle:

```
auto drawNode = DrawNode::create();
drawNode->drawDot(myPosition, myRadius, Color4F(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
//or use drawSolidCircle
```

now just add it wherever you want.

For "highlighting":

```
//loop through each all elements in range
element->setColor(someColor);
//or use shader, examples in cocos2d-x tests
```